# cut ip addresses from config file

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, output, cut

I have the following output:

```
vif         = [ 'ip=1.2.3.4, mac=00:00:00:00:00:00, bridge=eth1', 'ip=5.6.7.8, mac=00:00:00:00:00:00, bridge=eth1' ]
```

Sometimes, there is only one ip address. So it's:

```
vif         = [ 'ip=1.2.3.4, mac=00:00:00:00:00:00, bridge=eth1' ]
```

And in other cases, there are more than 2 ip addresses:

```
vif         = [ 'ip=1.2.3.4, mac=00:00:00:00:00:00, bridge=eth1', 'ip=5.6.7.8, mac=11:11:11:11:11:11, bridge=eth1', 'ip=9.1.2.3, mac=22:22:22:22:22:22, bridge=eth1' ]
```

Is there an easy way to get only the ip addresses? I want to store them in an array.

Comment: Use `grep` -- You'll find numerous such examples on this site.

Comment: Looks like a python or ruby array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possibility out of many: `tr -s "[,'" "\n" | grep "^ip=" | cut -d "=" -f2`

Example:

```
echo "vif         = [ 'ip=1.2.3.4, mac=00:00:00:00:00:00, bridge=eth1', 'ip=5.6.7.8, mac=11:11:11:11:11:11, bridge=eth1', 'ip=9.1.2.3, mac=22:22:22:22:22:22, bridge=eth1' ]" | tr -s "[,'" "\n" | grep "^ip=" | cut -d "=" -f2
```

produces

```
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
9.1.2.3
```

Comment: Your solution forgets the first ip (1.2.3.4). You should modify the tr command in: tr -s "[," "\n"

Comment: @JuniorDussouillez Thanks! I totally missed that the output wasn't correct.

Comment: Thank you! I will use your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

`I want to store them in an array.`

you can store your searched IP addresses in array as follows.

```
str="vif         = [ 'ip=1.2.3.4, mac=00:00:00:00:00:00, bridge=eth1', 'ip=5.6.7.8, mac=11:11:11:11:11:11, bridge=eth1', 'ip=9.1.2.3, mac=22:22:22:22:22:22, bridge=eth1' ]"

myarr=$(echo $str | tr -s "[,'" "\n" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/ip/){sub("ip=","",$i);print $i}}}')

for i in "${myarr[@]}"
do
  printf "%s \n" $i
done
```

Comment: I'm sure it works too. But the awk part is very complicated to me :P

Comment: @Vince ok as you like but it's different trick, Also you can use same trick to store ip in array by using "scai" method.

Answer (score 0):

a simple and understandable solution is: (data stored in `file`)

```
cat file | grep -o "'[^']*'" | grep -o "ip=[^,]*"
```

output:

```
ip=1.2.3.4
ip=5.6.7.8
ip=9.1.2.3
ip=1.2.3.4
ip=1.2.3.4
ip=5.6.7.8
```

to see only addresses:

```
cat file | grep -o "'[^']*'" | grep -o "ip=[^,]*" | cut -d"=" -f2
```

output:

```
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
9.1.2.3
1.2.3.4
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
```